# Нарисовать полукруг (pie) в QML и наложить OpocityMask

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Как в QML нарисовать полукруг и применить по нему маску прозрачности?
имеется изображение, от которого нужно рисовать только его часть - (полукруг как кусок пирога).

Необходимо задавать размер куска от 0 до 360 градусов. Не понимаю как такое реализовать в QML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил так: Реализовал класс C++, наследовал его от QQuickPaintedItem
переопределил метод paint:

```
void MyClass::paint(QPainter *painter){
    QBrush  brushActive(color);
    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->setBrush(brushActive);
    painter->drawPie(boundingRect(), 90 * 16, angle * 16);
}
```

Ну а далее регистрировал его в QML и накладывал нарисованный круг на изображение как маску через OpocityMask

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не правильно понял, но круг можно сделать через Rectangle{} выставив ему radius где-то 50 (точно не знаю). Потом внутри него сделать color: "transparent", также внутри создать Image{} и поместить туда свою картинку.

Возможно, это не то, что Вы хотели